# How does the compiler decides the order of functions in the import table

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-construction

Does the order of parsing effects the order of functions in the import table
 (i.e. first function encountered would be first in the import table?) or is it something else ?

Thanks!

EDIT
I'm using Visual Studio, but an answer about other compilers would be great as well!

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has nothing to do with it, the linker creates that table.  There is no preset order, simply the order in which the linker encounters exports in the object files.  You can make it predictable with a .def file.

There is no real point to it, the location of the export in the table doesn't affect anything.  The table entry is always located by ordinal or name, never position.  A GetProcAddress() micro-optimization is one you'll never see back in practice, disk I/O overhead blows it away.

Answer (score 1):

**Depends**. Dynamic linking and therefore DLLs and IATs are not part of standard C++ but an extension many compilers implement. In short, *if* and *how* they do it is compiler specific. Maybe the compiler you are using has something about it in the docs.